# Official list of countries for In-app Billing android?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Hello I am currently in Pakistan and when I start Google sample in-app billing application it says that

> "Can't Make Purchase: The market
>   billing service is not available at
>   this time. You can continue to use
>   this app but you won't be able to make
>   purchases."

Please if any body know that complete list of supported countries or knows what is going wrong please tell me.

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-implement

**UPDATE**

- Application has been uploaded on market but not published, uploaded as  a draft
- Product list has been created and published
- Application on device signed with same key, than application on market.
- Email registered in Market app is in test emails list.
- Android Market application version than 2.3.6
- Android OS version is 2.3.4 Nexus One

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you go here you country is not there http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?answer=150324
think thats the problem

Comment: Ok it means we can purchase apps with in-app billing in Pakistan but we can not sell apps win in-app billing within Pakistan. Thnx very much

Comment: @Aizaz yes unfutunetly that's truth as far as i know these is because it envolves a lots of money lawyers , coin , bla bla. but you can keep see news to see if you country was add to in-app billing

Comment: What if I root my phone and tells my phone that I live in US (it gets data from SIM that from where user belongs) So can I use in-app billing? It throws error on checkBillingSupported where it checks weather in-app billing is supported. although I can purchase apps within in Pakistan from Android Market. Its getting very confusing please tell me some way out. Regards Thnx

Comment: @Aizaz Well i think it get's the info from IP so one way out would VPN conection to internet to a country witch it is suported if that works tell me ok. VPN is not need to root phone but you need a VPN connection in other country. Regards

Comment: Actually I rooted the phone and now providing fake provider to Google that like I am in US and put T-Mobile SIM and its working but it really really sucks in implementation. Its tooooooooooooo hard to get through the stupid sample app and make things actually work. If you have some easy implementation then please tell me .

Answer (score 2):

There are may be several reasons.

- Application not uploaded on market.
- Application on device signed with different key (it may be debug key), than application on market.
- Email registered in Market app is not in test emails list.
- Android Market application version lower than 2.3.4

You can find checklist for testing [here](http://d.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-real).

List of countries is [here](https://market.android.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=143779&topic=1100168). Pakistan is in list.

**Upd**: @subspider is right. Pakistan is not in list of countries available for merchants. You may buy applications and do in-app purchases, but you can't publish paid applications or applications with in-app payments.

Quote from [In-App Billing Availability and Policies](http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?answer=1153481)

> In-app billing is available to developers in [supported locations for merchants](http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?answer=150324).

Comment: thnx let met update my question

Comment: thats not the list that list is for app top buy